# com.example.helloandroid.R.id cannot be resolved

Tags: android, unit-testing

I followed the [Hello, Testing tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html#CreateSetUp) to the letter.

Yet, the following line produces a "com.example.helloandroid.R.id cannot be resolved" error:

```
  mView = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(com.example.helloandroid.R.id.textview);
```

Eclipse amazingly suggests 2 quick fixes:

1. Create field 'id' in type 'R'
2. Create constant 'id' in type 'R'

Can you help me understand what these fixes mean? Are these really the correct fixes? (why didn't the tutorial provide them, too?)

Comment: can you post the layout file where the TextView with id textview is declared ?

Comment: +1 for pointing at the (non-existent) layout file. That was the source of the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In HelloAndroid project, HelloAndroid.java

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Check your HelloAndroid project, in "gen->com.example.helloandroid->R.java" have the following code like:

```
public static final class id {
 public static final int textview=0x7f050000;
}
```

if no, check "res->layout->main.xml". there is "android:id="@+id/textview" as follows?

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/textview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:text="@string/hello"/>
```

check these items, fix your HelloAndroid.java and/or main.xml if needed.
rebuild HelloAndroid project, and rebuild HelloAndroidTest project.

Comment: I don't know how to rebuild my project , but I debug it and the problem solved thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> > Are these really the correct fixes?

None of them.

What you have to do is importing the correct `R` class. Sometimes eclipse help you with that when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

Comment: This is also wrong. You shouldn't import any R. It's autogenerated and it's not necessary to import. Just clean and rebuild the project. If it still doesn't work, it means you have an error in your XML

Comment: Wait... what do you mean by "it's autogenerated"? And why isn't necessary to import it?

Comment: @Falmarri : You should post it as a new answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: Both of you helped me understand the correct direction. I haven't solved the problem yet but I at least I understand why it occurred: I was using the first non-XML HelloAndroid tutorial. The one that's using main.xml for layout is named HelloAndroidXML. Still learning...

Comment: @Falmarri: here you are wrong, Christian's answer is very possibly correct. You do of course need an import statement to get hold of your R-variables. Normally Eclipse will add the correct import, but if you for instance use both your own R-variables and the global R-variables (com.android.R, isn't that the package?) in the same file, Eclipse might not know which one to use, and you'll have to explicitly specify it yourself.

Comment: And @downvoter: there is nothing wrong with Christian's suggested answer, so the down-vote is totally undeserved!

Comment: @Nailuj thanks, that's what I think. I'd like to see what @Falmarrri thinks though; may be I could learn something new from him.

Comment: @Nailuj: That's not right. You don't need to import R. The reason that eclipse imports the wrong R is that if you have a problem in your XML, the R.java (in your project) doesn't get generated, and thus the only R that eclipse can find is the android.R class and it imports that.

Comment: Ahh, I got your point! By import I meant: "the import statement must be there" not "you have to manually import it". Even if Eclipse does that automatically for you, you are importing it (otherwise the code won't compile). Good for you that Eclipse exists... can't imagine you working on Emacs.

Comment: @Falmarri: we might be talking around each other, but I still think you're wrong. If I create an empty empty activity (a simple class extending `Activity`), the only import present from the start is `android.app.Activity`. If I then create an empty function and start typing `int i = R.`, the intellisense suggests both values from my own R.java and the global R.java in `android.R`. If I then choose a value from the global, that one will be added to the import statements. I will then not be able to access my own R.java unless I explicitly specify the full path, or change the import statement.

Comment: The only point I'm trying to make is that it is very much possible that one (even with correctly formatted XML) end up having the wrong import for the `R` class :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert.  But I can tell you that this problem also happened to me.  Thanks to the comments above, I figured out that between the time I worked the Hello World tutorial and the time that I tried the Hello World Testing tutorial, I had tried the Linear Layout tutorial in the "Hello, Views" section.  Following the Linear Layout tutorial, I changed main.xml.

I restored main.xml to the way in which the Hello World tutorial expected it and that solved the missing "id" problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a noob myself but recently came across this (or a similar) problem. You shouldn't have to import your R class because you give it an fully-qualified package name (com.yourpackage.R...) in the findviewById and the R class is public. *However*, if like me you had put both your project and your test project in the same package you are probably referencing your *test* R class not your project's R class.

Changing my test manifest to be com.mypackage.test instead of com.mypackage (and moving any subsequent misplaced classes to the new com.mypackage.test) fixed the problem (you may have to delete your test R class for it to be regenerated)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well while following the Android training for creating tests. None of the above solutions worked - a R.java class was continuously created within the **MyFirstAppTest** project, and this is the R class that was picked up in the **MainActivityTest** class. The only way that I could resolve it was to import the R class from the project under test (in my **MainActivityTest.java** file):

```
import com.example.myfirstapp.R;
```

Then the correct R class was picked up along with its id method.